# Skip $timeout during Protractor tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

I've added a minimum wait time for ajax in my application, but I would like my e2e tests to complete as quickly as possible. Can protractor be forced to skip waiting for `$timeout` to finish its wait time?

```
$timeout(function() {
    deferment.resolve(response);
}, waitTimeRemaining);
```

During e2eTests, I would like waitTimeRemaning to be skipped and move straight to the resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works in protractor (never used it), but you should be able to do

```
$timeout.flush(waitTimeRemaining)
```

to synchronously flush the queue of deferred functions that would happen in the next `waitTimeRemaining` milliseconds.

This only works when you are using the angular mock `$timeout`.

[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/%24timeout)